# Appmenu not working in libreoffice4.0

Tags: libreoffice, appmenu

I manually downloaded and installed libreoffice, but know the global-menu wont work.

I tried to install the `lo-menubar` package but that didn't work.

[image: lo-menubar]

**Question**: *how to get the libreoffice menubar to work*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [libreoffice ppa](https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/ppa) have been update to the latest, and thus also fixing the global-menu to work. Here is the description from the Libreoffice ppa

> LibreOffice test builds and backports
>
> Note: For the current development release this ppa might even contain
>   alpha and beta releases!
>
> There is a PPA dedicated to specific LibreOffice major series which
>   support a range of older Ubuntu releases too:
>   https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-3-4
>   https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-3-5
>   https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-3-6
>   https://launchpad.net/~libreoffice/+archive/libreoffice-4-0
>
> Most of the packages in this PPA have only experienced minor testing
>   -- in fact it is the place to enable a wider audience to test packages before they are published into the distro proper. In general, this PPA
>   is *not* for the average user to install without a closer look (if it
>   would be, its packages would be in the main repositories).
>
> In general, users are advised to take a look at the changelog for the
>   details about a package. If there is a specific bug that is intended
>   to be addressed by an update released into the PPA, you are encouraged
>   to test, if the update solves that problem. Packages published after
>   the distro release are mostly such specific fixes. Critical fixes will
>   be SRUed into the main repositories after testing anyway (later, with
>   more testing).

Answer (score 1):

This has been reported elsewhere, as not yet working for **12.04** and **12.10**.

They appear to have focused on the next Ubuntu release (**13.04**), so you need to be patient, or try this on 13.04.

[WebUpd8 > LibreOffice 4.0 Available For Download](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/02/libreoffice-40-available-for-download.html)

> **The Document Foundation has released LibreOffice 4.0 today**, which, according to the official announcement, is the "first release that reflects the objectives set by the community at the time of the announcement, in September 2010: a cleaner and leaner code base, an improved set of features, better interoperability, and a more diverse and inclusive ecosystem".

This also notes:

> However, **the appmenu integration by default didn't work in my test under Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10** (with LibreOffice debs downloaded from its website). This does work with the LibreOffice 4.0 beta 2 version available in the LibreOffice **Pre-Releases PPA** for Ubuntu 13.04.